# How do i create leanback layout with banner

Tags: android, kotlin, leanback, listrowpresenter

I want layout something like in this picture

[custom leanback layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF6JO.png)

I tried to add custom RowPresenter to the BrowseFragment's Adapter
However I my custom view didn't cover full width with "match_parent" attribute,

And when focus shifts to items of ListRow banner of custom RowPresenter moves upward and gets hidden.

Here is the code

MainBrowseFragment ->

```
var rowPresenterSelector = ClassPresenterSelector();
rowPresenterSelector.addClassPresenter(ListRow::class.java,ListRowPresenter())
rowPresenterSelector.addClassPresenter(CustomRow::class.java,CustomRowPresenter())
arrayObjectAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(rowPresenterSelector)
arrayObjectAdapter.add(CustomRow());
```

Here is my Custom Row Presenter with custom view with banner.

```
class CustomRowPresenter: RowPresenter() {
    override fun createRowViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?): ViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_row_presenter,null,false)
        return ViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```